# Angular with RESFTful Rails APIs or Firebase APIs ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, rest, firebase

I am looking for advice to save me time. I am planning to create a Q&A web app for my university, a stackoverflow clone. I know Rails and I know Angular but I never used them together. One option for me is to use Firebase APIs because it's simple. My question is which is easier, making Angular consume Rails APIs, or firebase APIs? Or is it the same steps no matter what I use to create the APIs ?

Comment: Is your question should I build my own Rails API or use the Firebase API?

Comment: @thatkindofmatt Yes, which is easier for Angular to communicate with? is it same process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This is not going to be the same process. It's also not a direct comparison.

Firebase is a hosted third party 'backend-as-a-service' and you use what they give you for API calls, but you can more or less rely on the API working as advertised (though the docs can be less than useful in places).

That is vs building your own RoR API, which means just that - you pick the groceries just as you want them, but you also get to fix all the bugs on both your API and and your client. You also still need a DB selected.

A more direct comparison would be 'should I pick Node or RoR.' Your question as it's posed is really a question of your own backend implementation or a hosted package.

2. Which is easier?

There is not a real, single answer.

If by easier you mean 'most direct', Firebase has an [Angular library called AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html). It translates a lot of Firebase paradigms into a pretty familiar Angular pattern, with a couple of nice extras. You focus on your client code and DB design, it handles the server operations. That seems fairly direct to me.

If by easier you mean 'most flexibility', it's hard to see how building your own doesn't give you that.

If by easier you mean 'less work for me', then 'it depends'. If you are comfortable writing RoR backends and less familiar with NoSQL patterns, then you can probably put it together faster on your own setting your API methods and selecting a DB you are comfortable with. If you feel stronger with Angular than RoR, then learning Firebase paradigms might be a shorter climb.

For what it's worth, given its limited set of API calls, there is probably more focused support for specific questions about Firebase. But you do sacrifice the option of doing it 'your way,' and the RoR community is far larger than Firebase's so you can probably still get plenty of help. Like I said, it can really depend.